# z3 4.3.2 fails to find a model for Why3-generated (satisfiable) goals

Tags: z3, why3

I'm trying to use Why3's Z3 back-end in order to retrieve models that can then be used to derive test cases exhibiting bugs in programs. However, Z3 version 4.3.2 seems unable to answer `sat` for any Why3 goal. It looks like some of the axiomatic definitions used by Why3 somehow confuse Z3. For instance, the following example (which is a tiny part of what Why3 generates)

```
(declare-fun abs1 (Int) Int)

;; abs_def
  (assert
  (forall ((x Int)) (ite (<= 0 x) (= (abs1 x) x) (= (abs1 x) (- x)))))

(check-sat)
```

results in `timeout` with the following command line:

```
z3 -smt2 model.partial=true file.smt2 -T:10
```

On the other hand, changing the definition to

```
(declare-fun abs1 (Int) Int)

;; abs_def
  (assert
  (forall ((x Int)) (=> (<= 0 x) (= (abs1 x) x))))

  (assert
  (forall ((x Int)) (=> (> 0 x) (= (abs1 x) (- x)))))
```

will get me a model (which looks pretty reasonable)

```
(model 
  (define-fun abs1 ((x!1 Int)) Int
    (ite (>= x!1 0) x!1 (* (- 1) x!1)))
)
```

but if I try to add the next axiom present in the original Why3 file, namely

```
;; Abs_pos
(assert (forall ((x Int)) (<= 0 (abs1 x))))
```

again Z3 answers `timeout`.

Is there something I'm missing in the configuration of Z3? Moreover, in previous versions of Why3, there was an option `MODEL_ON_TIMEOUT`, which allowed to retrieve a model in such circumstances. Even though there was no guarantee that this was a real model since Z3 could not finish to check it, in practice such models generally contained all the information I needed. However, I haven't found a similar option in 4.3.2. Does it still exist?

**Update** The last axiom `Abs_pos` was wrong (I toyed a bit with Why3's output before posting here and ended up pasting an incorrect version of the issue). This is now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The additional axiom

> (assert (not (forall ((x Int)) (<= 0 (abs1 x)))))

makes the problem unsatisfiable, since abs1 always returns a non-negative integer and with the additional axiom you require the existence of a negative result for abs1 for some x. The web version of Z3 returns unsat as expected, see [here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/ucQo).

Comment: Oops, I realize that I pasted the wrong part of my attempts to toy with Why3's output. the real axiom provided by Why3 is of course `(assert (forall ((x Int)) (<= 0 (abs1 x))))`. I'll edit my question accordingly, sorry for the noise.